# Using strtok to run multiple commands

Tags: c, shell, strtok

I'm trying to create a shell using C that can take multiple commands separated by a semicolon(;). Currently I'm trying to use strtok to separate the commands but I don't think I'm using it correctly. I'll post all the info I can without posting the entire code. Is strtok being used correctly?

```
char *semi=";";
 else
            {
                    char *token=strtok(str,semi);
                    if(token != NULL)
                    {
                            token=strtok(NULL,semi);
                    if((childpid = fork()) == 0)
                    {
                            if ((execvp(args[0], args))<0)//prints error message when unknown command is used
                            {
                                    printf("Error! Command not recognized.\n");
                            }
                            execvp(args[0],args);
                            free(args);//deallocate args
                            exit(0);
                    }
```

Edit: As per instructed I removed a large chunk of the code originally posted to focus solely on the use of strtok. When compiled the makeshift shell will accept one command at a time. I'm trying to use ";" to separate and run two commands simultaneously. Am I using strtok correctly? If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example - something that can be compiled.

Comment: And remove all of the dead code (code in comments). Just show us your current code.

Comment: I would need to share the entire code so it functions properly. Would it be better to post the entire thing so you and others could compile it yourselves? I was hoping just the strtok piece would be enough, but I can post more.

Comment: It would not be good to post the entire thing. Instead, put a small wrapper around the code to demonstrate how the code works, and any problems that you're facing. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I'm still pretty new to coding/SO and from the link you shared with me it indicates to make the code as simple as possible. I'm not really sure on how to make the code compile when broken down. Would it be easier to just edit and highlight the use of strtok?

Comment: Sure, let's give that a try.

Comment: I have updated my post and added some more info, hopefully that helps.

Comment: The first call `token=strtok(str,semi)` will give you the string up to the first semicolon. The second call will give you the string between the first and second semicolon. But the code doesn't appear to use either result. You can see what `strtok` does by starting with `char str[] = "hello;world;"`, and then `printf("%s\n", token)` after each call to `strtok`.

Comment: It can't be seen right now but str is the input from the user of the shell. So my understanding was, take the line of input, check where a semicolon appears, delete the semicolon and separate the string into two separate lines. How do I use those lines of string after it separates them?

Comment: After breaking `str` into lines, you'll need to break each line into an array `args`, using the space character as the delimiter.

Comment: That's going to be my last comment on this question. The way SO is supposed to work is that you present your problem, and ask a specific question. The question should be something that can be answered in a paragraph or two. But the impression that I'm getting is that you need help from a tutor. That's not what this site is about.

Comment: Sorry, i would usually be in a tutor, but it's spring break and the center is closed. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check, if `strtok()` returns `NULL`. I would change the structure as follows:

```
char* semi = ";"; // Your semikolon
char *token = NULL; // Your token string

// ...
// Split first occour of semicolon
token = strtok(str,semi);
if(token == NULL){
    perror("No command given ...");
    return NULL;
}
do {
    // Execute your code here
    // fork() etc.
    // You should get each line (each semikolon seperated string)
    // and it should be stored into token
} while((token = strtok(NULL, semi) != NULL);
```

I hope, I did understand your problem right ...

But as I can see, you need to split the `token` again by spaces to get them into a `char`-Array for the `argv[]` (second parameter) of `execvp()`. Here the problem is, that `strtok()` internally uses a `static` (?) variable to store the last position. So using another `strtok()` inside the loop would "destroy" your text.

You could do something like this:

```
char *str; // Your string ...
char semi[1] = ";"; // Your semikolon AND space; strtok() will split at both
char *token = NULL; // Your token string
int len = 0;
char *token2;
int argvpos = 0;

// ...
// Split first occour of semicolon
token = strtok(str,semi);
if(token == NULL){
    perror("No command given ...");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
do {
    // save length of token
    len = strlen(token);
    // Split for blanks to get the arguments
    token2 = strtok(token," ");
    // Build array of arguments
    while(token2 != NULL){
        args[argvpos++] = token2;
        token2 = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    // Do something with token (as command)
    // and args (as arguments)
    // ...
} while((token = strtok(token+len+1, semi) != NULL);
// In the while condition you add the length to the token; so you get the "old" last position
```

I think it is not a good solution, but it should work. And I hope, I did understand you problem ;-)

Kind regards.

Comment: I went into my tutoring center and had them help/explain it. This answer was very close to how we solved my problem, thanks for putting in so much effort to help!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you want to accept my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to work correctly, `strtok` should be used along with a while loop. Also, you don't need to run `execvp` twice.

I created a small sample program using your code to demonstrate how you can correctly use your code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "ls -1; echo 'hello world'"; // Input commands separated by ';'

  // Break the commands string into an array
  char *commands[10]; // Array to hold a max of 10 commands
  char *semi = ";";
  char *token = strtok(str, semi);
  int i = 0;
  while (token != NULL) 
  {
    commands[i] = token;
    ++i;
    token = strtok(NULL, semi);
  }
  int numCommands = i; // numCommands is the max number of input commands

  // Run each input command in a child process
  i = 0;
  while (i < numCommands)
  {
    printf("Command: %s\n", commands[i]);

    // Tokenize the command so that it can be run using execvp
    char *args[10] = {}; // Array to hold command args
    args[0] = strtok(commands[i], " ");
    int tokenCounter = 0;
    while (args[tokenCounter] != NULL)
    {
      tokenCounter++;
      args[tokenCounter] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Create a child process
    int childpid = fork();

    // If this is child process, run the command
    if (childpid == 0)
    {
      if ((execvp(args[0], args)) < 0)
      {
        printf("Error! Command not recognized.\n");
      }
      exit(0);
    }
    // If this is the parent, wait for the child to finish
    else if (childpid > 0)
    {
      wait(&childpid);
    }
    // If the child process could not be created, print an error and exit
    else
    {
      printf("Error: Could not create a child process.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    ++i;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a great answer +1 for this I was googling connecting multiple commands on stdin in pipes and reached here.